# Cross-compile qemu for ARM

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, qemu

I need to cross-compile qemu to use it on a cubieboard2 with an ARM Cortex-A7 CPU and I'm cross-compiling it on Linux Mint.

I can't find anywhere the commands I need to use to do it, the only thing I could find is how to compile qemu on an emulated ARM system.  This is what I tried:

```
git clone git://git.qemu-project.org/qemu.git

./configure --target-list="arm-softmmu arm-linux-user" --prefix=/usr --enable-kvm --enable-linux-user --enable-user --enable-system

make ARCH=ARM CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
```

I don't get any errors, everything seems fine, but I don't get an executable file that I can use on my board.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: IMO, it's [far too easy](http://www.bing.com/search?q=cross-compile+qemu&pc=MOZI&form=MOZCON) to find [several](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2011-05/msg00099.html) [results](https://wiki.linaro.org/Platform/DevPlatform/CrossCompile/QemuCrossCompile) that imply the appropriate way to specify a cross-compiler prefix...

Comment: @Agostina Have you got any solutions